# how to install timezone 2019 leaps for mysql 8

Tags: mysql, timezone

I'm having problems with the time zone on MySQL 8 was wondering ware to copy it to.. I'm running Windows 10 Pro.. do I install it in the base directory of MySQL or on the external drive ware I have my database data?

Answer (score 3):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html

Time-zone infomation AFAIK is usually derived directly from the operating system.

Comment: I have downloaded the time zone info file now ware to put for it to take affect?, the problem i'm having is a 7 hour discrepancy I've tried a function called convert_TZ and it comes back with null